# Humanizing paths in Windows

Tags: winapi, path, rust

The [directories](https://github.com/soc/directories-rs) crate internally stores paths in Windows in their long form, such as `//?/C:/Users/roey/.emacs.d`. These paths are printed in this form when their `.display()` method is called, which is not very human friendly. Is there any way to humanize these paths without creating `String` and calling `.replace()`?

Comment: What is the reason of using such a library? Avoid all Linux things in Windows, especially if you look for user friendliness. The fact that it stores the directory with /s shows ignorance of Windows naming styles. Please avoid all these libraries.

Comment: `Path` has method [`as_os_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.as_os_str), does it return the path in the desired format?